# Run shell script file rails controller with argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a shell script file in the rails application.Can anyone please tell me how can i call the shell script file with argument in my rails controller?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try backticks (``` `` ```). For example `` a = `date` `` would assign shell's `date` command output to the `a` variable.

UPD: And you can obviously run something like `` `~/workspace/my_script.sh` `` to execute a script from a file, just make sure you give it executable permission first (with `chmod +x ~/workspace/my_script.sh`).

UPD2: And for the parameters, you can just interpolate them, like so `` `~/workspace/my_script.sh #{my_parameter_one}` ``. `my_parameter_one` will be available in the script as `$1`.